# JOGL inside VMWare - texture updates not seen

Tags: java, opengl, vmware, jogl

I've got a piece of code that works fine under Windows 7 native, or Ubuntu 16.04 native, however with Ubuntu 16.04 inside VMPlayer 6 with vmwgfx it does not update unless you move the window. Exactly the same code in all 3 cases.

Node this is with older JOGL 1

- http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/master/gluegen-old-1.0b6/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar
- http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/master/gluegen-old-1.0b6/gluegen-rt.jar
- http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/master/jogl-old-1.1.1/jogl.jar
- http://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/master/jogl-old-1.1.1/jogl-natives-linux-amd64.jar

Code

```
public class JoglTest2 {

    public static class JoglPanel extends GLJPanel {
        public JoglPanel() {
            addGLEventListener(new EventListener());
            new FPSAnimator(this, 10).start();
        }
    }

    public static class EventListener implements GLEventListener {

        private int textureData;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 200;
        private int clock;

        @Override
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();

            gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0, 0.5f, 1);

            gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.textureData);

            int[] data = new int[width];
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int red = (x + clock) % 255;
                int green = 0;
                int blue = 127;
                data[x] = 255 | (blue << 8) | (green << 16) | (red << 24);
            }
            clock++;
            IntBuffer dataBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(data);
            gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, (clock % height), width, 1, GL.GL_RGBA,
                    GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, dataBuffer);

            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
            gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
            gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
            gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0);
            gl.glVertex2f(1.f, -1.0f);
            gl.glEnd();
        }

        @Override
        public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable arg0, boolean arg1, boolean arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            final int[] tmp = new int[1];
            gl.glGenTextures(1, tmp, 0);
            textureData = tmp[0];

            int[] data = new int[width * height];
            IntBuffer dataBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(data);
            gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.textureData);
            gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,
                    dataBuffer);
            gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                    GL.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                    GL.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                    GL.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                    GL.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            int shaderId = gl.glCreateShader(GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            final String[] strs = {             "uniform sampler2D inputTexture;\n"+
                    "void main(void) {\n" +
                    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputTexture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);\n" +
                    "}\n"
            };
            gl.glShaderSource(shaderId, strs.length, strs, (int[]) null, 0);

            gl.glCompileShader(shaderId);
            int progId = gl.glCreateProgram();
            gl.glAttachShader(progId, shaderId);
            gl.glLinkProgram(progId);

            int uniformInputTexture = gl.glGetUniformLocation(progId, "inputTexture");
            gl.glUseProgram(progId);
            gl.glUniform1i(uniformInputTexture, 0);

        }

        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JoglPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Windows

[image: Windows 7]

Ubuntu 16.04 inside VMWare

[image: Ubuntu 16.04]

I've spent a lot of time looking at guides on how to do this, but can't spot the issue causing it to fail in Linux. Other OpenGL apps, glxgears etc. work fine...

```
glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Why don't use updated libs?

Comment: It's a legacy project, no one will want to risk migration

Comment: The JOGL guys essentially deprecated JOGL 1 because new hardware surfaced bugs that couldn't be fixed without new features that went into later JOGL versions. You're almost certainly running into one of those bugs. There isn't a way forward short of finding the bug yourself and fixing it.

Comment: I confirm that we only maintain JOGL 2. JOGL 1 was abandoned in 2010. Please switch to JOGL 2.3.2. I don't know your constraints but it's nonsensical to use an obsolete version of a library not maintained for almost 6 years in production. JOGL 2 is actively maintained. A port from JOGL 1 to JOGL 2 is quite trivial even though some import clauses and some public APIs have changed, I can help you to do it. Moreover, Oracle VirtualBox works correctly with JOGL 2 but I can't confirm that similar tools work flawlessly with it (typically Parallels has a bug prevent it from working with JOGL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to forward is to migrate the existing code to JOGL2. In this case it performs as expected within VMWare. Port to JOGL2 is fairly straightforward.